# FirebaseUI needs pending intent

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, android-pendingintent, activity-result-api

I have a code which goes to firebaseAuthUI with this activityResultLauncher:

```
        //used for login
    this.loginActivityLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract(),
        result -> {
            String s;
            //result success
            if(result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                user.SignIn(MainActivity.this);
                s = getString(R.string.welcome);
            }
            //user exited login screen
            else if(result.getIdpResponse() == null){
                s = getString(R.string.error_login_cancelled);
            }
            //error
            else {
                s = Objects.requireNonNull(result.getIdpResponse().getError()).getLocalizedMessage();
                Utils.AlertBuild(null, s, null, MainActivity.this).show();
            }

            updateData(s);//update screen
    });
```

But when I try my app with a newer OS the app crashes with this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bigproject, PID: 2013
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.bigproject: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:401)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:484)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:470)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:434)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzr.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.0.0:19)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.CredentialsClient.getHintPickerIntent(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.0.0:10)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CheckPhoneHandler.fetchCredential(CheckPhoneHandler.java:28)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CheckPhoneNumberFragment.setDefaultCountryForSpinner(CheckPhoneNumberFragment.java:246)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CheckPhoneNumberFragment.onActivityCreated(CheckPhoneNumberFragment.java:130)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2996)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:580)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:285)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1467)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7945)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3750)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2272)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7902)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:933)
```

I didn't find a way to convert or launch firebaseAuthUI with pending intent and I also make the Intent by this code and I don't know how to change it to PendingIntent:

```
    public Intent createIntent() {
        return AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(Collections.singletonList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build()))
                .setLogo(R.drawable.main_act_img)
                .build();
    }
```